# I'm trying to make a string class with static memory array

Tags: c++, string, class, aggregate-initialization

This is just for fun, I know i can use the std and not reinvent the wheel, etc.

This is essentially my class:

```cpp
template<size_t size>
class sstring {
public:
    char buffer[size];
};
```

I want to be able to use it like this:

```cpp
sstring<> str1 = "My string";      // One possible way
sstring str2 = "My other string";  // Another possible way
```

But the closest i get is: `sstring<n> str = { "..." };`, I don't quite understand why it cannot infer the size by itself and I would like it to do so.

Without templates I get a bit closer: `sstring str = { "..." };`.

I realized it happens because that's how aggregate initialization works, so i tried with a public constructor, but lost the aggregate advantages.

Then tried to overload the `=` operator, but still get the aggregate construction syntax.

I want to keep my class as an aggregate type and be able to construct it as any of the 'possible' examples above.

I would also like to keep the template so i can provide the size in case i can't / don't want to provide the value immediately, but it's not necessary.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: I don't see anything `static` about this.

Comment: Sorry, i meant static as static array, not the static keyword. @user207421

Comment: But you aren't using a static array. The word `static `does not appear in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I missed the aggregate part of the question. I will leave this answer nevertheless as you might not be aware of CTAD.

If you write a constructor that accepts a reference to a c-string you can make use of [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>

template<size_t size>
class sstring {
public:
    sstring(const char (&b)[size]) {
        std::copy(b,b+size,buffer);
    }
    char buffer[size];
};

int main() {
    sstring foo = "asd";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4xx46fG8o)

The explicit deduction guide would be

```
template <size_t size>
sstring(const char (&b)[size]) -> sstring<size>;
```

---

I cannot completely explain why the constructor is needed. It has to do with array to pointer decay. Without the constructor you can get this though:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>

template<size_t size>
class sstring {
public:
    char buffer[size];
};

template<class... U >
sstring(U... ) -> sstring<1 + sizeof...(U)>;

int main() {
    sstring foo{'a','b','c'};
}
```

Inpsired from the deduction guide for `std::array` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides)

Comment: I'm aware of CTAD but don't understand why it cannot deduct the size without a constructor, probably I'm missing something but don't really know what :(

Comment: @Dain i cannot explain in formal terms, but it has to do with array to pointer decay. Consider this https://godbolt.org/z/vjz3b7d1c. Without a constructor that takes a reference to the array (and deduces the size) the array decays

Comment: I was tinkering with your solution and the `std::array`, got to understand about the pointer decay, seems like my idea is just not viable as I wanted it to be. Thanks for your answer, I leave a bit more knowledgeable :)